# How do I get an INTEGER and turn that into an ARRAY of separate single digit integers in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, integer, mips

Okay so I have an issue. I want to get an integer and turn it into an array of single-digit integers in MIPS but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Can you guys help me? I know how to do this in every other language except this one...

Example:
I want to the integer 32325
to be an array where A[0] = 3, A[1] = 2, A[2] = 3, ...

Can you please help me? I've been stumped for a while!
This is what I have so far...

```
.data
     prompt: .asciiz
     msg: .asciiz
     array: .space 24 #6 digit number

.text
    li $v0, 4 #print out
    la $a0, prompt1 
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #take in int
    syscall

    la $a0, array# Set address t0 to be the array
```

Comment: _"I know how to do this in every other language"_. Ok, so you know the algorithm already. Then you need to be more specific about what the problem is. Which operation do you need to perform that you didn't feel was adequatly described in the MIPS instruction set reference?

Comment: *"in every other language"* ... :D ... ever been introduced to "brainfuck" programming language? :) Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about MIPS, but the algorithm is quite simple

Divide the number by 10, as long as it is != 0 ... the reminders (in reverse order) are the digits. easiest way to store them would be the stack, since pop'ing them will bring them into correct order again:

```
counter=0
while (number !=0) {
   push number%10
   number /= 10
   counter++
}
while (counter>0) {
   pop number
   store/display it
   counter--
}
```